# Partial deserialization with Apache Avro

Tags: avro

Is it possible to deserialize a subset of fields from a large object serialized using Apache Avro without deserializing all the fields? I'm using `GenericDatumReader` and the `GenericRecord` contains all the fields.

I'm pretty sure you can't do it using `GenericDatumReader`, but my question is whether it is possible given the binary format of Avro.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, binary serialization of Avro data is in-order and depth-first. As you traverse the data, record fields are serialized one after the other, lists are serialized from the top to the bottom, etc.

Within one object, there no markers to separate fields, no tags to identify specific fields, and no index into the binary data to help quickly scan to specific fields.

Depending on your schema, you ***could*** write custom code to skip *some* kinds of data ... for example, ***if*** a field is a LIST of FIXED bytes, you could read the size of the list and just jump over the data to the next field.  This is pretty specific and wouldn't work for most Avro types though (notably integers are variable length when encoded).

Even in that unlikely case, I don't believe there are any helpers in the Java SDK that would be useful.

In brief, Avro isn't designed to do that, and you're probably not going to find a satisfactory way to do a projection on your Schema without deserializing the entire object.  If you have a collection, column-oriented persistence like Parquet is probably the right thing to do!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the fields you want to read occur first in the record. We do this in some cases where we want to read only the header fields of an object, not the full data which follows.

You can create a "subset" schema containing just those first fields, and pass this to GenericDatumReader. Avro will deserialise those fields, and anything which comes after will be ignored, because the schema doesn't "know" about it.

But this won't work for the general case where you want to pick out fields from within the middle of a record.